# C++ array size is always 4

Tags: c++, arrays

Hi I have an array defined in my header filed

```
private:
    Customer** customerListArray;
```

In my cpp file I set it as following,

```
customerListArray = new Customer* [data.size()];
cout << "arr size " << data.size() << "\n";
cout << "arr size " << sizeof(customerListArray) << "\n";
```

However data.size() is 11900, but sizeof(customerListArray) array is always 4. I've tried replacing data.size() with 100 and still I get 4.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you.

Comment: You are looking at the size of a pointer in bytes.

Comment: If you do a 64 bit build, it will be 8 bytes.

Comment: Fundamental misunderstanding here is that to the *compiler* customerListArray is a pointer. You may know at run time that you make it point to an array, but the compiler doesn't know that and sizeof operates at compile time. The answer of course is to use `std::vector` instead, so you can use `size()`

Comment: the reason i'm using array is, it's a requirement of this assessment

Comment: For OP: And to get total number of elements use `sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])` that is equals to `100` in @fayyazki's example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pointers are always of fixed size and the OP is using pointer. For **sizeof()** to return the actual length of an array, you have to declare an array and pass it's name to sizeof().

```
int arr[100];

sizeof(arr); // This would be 400 (assuming int to be 4 and num elements is 100)

int *ptr = arr;

sizeof(ptr); // This would be 4 (assuming pointer to be 4 bytes on this platform.
```

It is also important to note that sizeof() returns **number of bytes** and not *number of elements*

Answer (score 2):

because `customerListArray` is a pointer

Answer (score 1):

sizeof() returns the size in bytes of an element, in this case your 'customer**' is 4 bytes in size.
[See this page for reference on sizeof()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof).

Comment: The `SizeOfArray` idiom will not help here. It is useful when the size of the array is static. And anyway, there is [`std::extent`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/extent), so why write it yourself?

Comment: Sorry, but this is wrong. He/she's taking the size of `Customer**` which is a pointer type and in his particular platform pointers are 4 bytes long. `sizeof(Customer)` might not be 4.